# Virtual COM for Mac OS

Tags: mac-osx, command-line-interface, serial, com

IS there a way to create virtual COM ports in Mac OS and connect them to eachother?

Comment: Can you tell us why?  It may help us provide better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this thread on *daemonforums.org* contains a hint of the options you have:

**http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=634**

> I had an email from the author of
>   netfwd to let me know that it doesn't
>   support pty. He recommended I try
>   socat, which worked perfectly!
>
> ```
>  # socat GOPEN:/dev/ptyp0,ignoreeof TCP:10.0.1.93:10002
> ```
>
> Then point the application at
>   /dev/ttyp0

Comment: This does not work in High Sierra. Gives "Resource temporarily unavailable" error. Any ideas?